# How to handle associations and nested forms in Phoenix framework?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

What is the way to handle associations and nested forms in Phoenix framework? How would one create a form with nested attributes? How would one handle it in the controller and model?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a simple example of handling 1-1 situation.

Imagine we have a `Car` and an `Engine` models and obviously a `Car` has_one `Engine`. So there's code for the car model

```
defmodule MyApp.Car do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "cars" do
    field :name, :string            

    has_one :engine, MyApp.Engine

    timestamps
  end

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, ~w(name), ~w())
    |> validate_length(:name, min: 5, message: "No way it's that short")    
  end

end
```

and the engine model

```
defmodule MyApp.Engine do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "engines" do
    field :type, :string            

    belongs_to :car, MyApp.Car

    timestamps
  end

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, ~w(type), ~w())
    |> validate_length(:type, max: 10, message: "No way it's that long")    
  end

end
```

Simple template for the form ->

```
<%= form_for @changeset, cars_path(@conn, :create), fn c -> %>

  <%= text_input c, :name %>

  <%= inputs_for c, :engine, fn e -> %>

    <%= text_input e, :type %>

  <% end %>  

  <button name="button" type="submit">Create</button>

<% end %>
```

and the controller ->

```
defmodule MyApp.CarController do
  use MyApp.Web, :controller
  alias MyApp.Car
  alias MyApp.Engine

  plug :scrub_params, "car" when action in [:create]

  def new(conn, _params) do    
    changeset = Car.changeset(%Car{engine: %Engine{}})    
    render conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset
  end

  def create(conn, %{"car" => car_params}) do    
    engine_changeset = Engine.changeset(%Engine{}, car_params["engine"])
    car_changeset = Car.changeset(%Car{engine: engine_changeset}, car_params)
    if car_changeset.valid? do
      Repo.transaction fn ->
        car = Repo.insert!(car_changeset)
        engine = Ecto.Model.build(car, :engine)
        Repo.insert!(engine)
      end
      redirect conn, to: main_page_path(conn, :index)
    else
      render conn, "new.html", changeset: car_changeset
    end
  end    

end
```

and an interesting blog post on the subject that can clarify some things as well -> [here](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/08/working-with-ecto-associations-and-embeds/)

Comment: The example can have some minor errors since I didn't have a chance to property test it or be written in not an exactly correct way since I am new  to this framework myself but I hope it'll help somebody to save a little time figuring those things out for himself. Just trying to make finding answers to some questions easier since there is not a lot of info on the subject

Comment: The problem with this solution if that if for instance `Car` would have a constrain like uniqueness for its name, then the transaction would fail and no error would be given for the form. I'm stucked in this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38035026?noredirect=1

Comment: Here's a test showing how you would do the nested insert in ecto 2, https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/6f1971f4120b84e1a441792feb77ba451c4fc783/integration_test/cases/repo.exs#L720

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the same problem with a `has_many` relationship. Unfortunately, a `Car` cannot have many `Engines`, so I'd take the same example in this [blogpost](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/08/working-with-ecto-associations-and-embeds/), of a `TodoList`, with many `TodoItems`

`TodoList` model:

```
defmodule MyApp.TodoList do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "todo_lists" do
    field :title, :string            

    has_many :todo_items, MyApp.TodoItem

    timestamps
  end
 
  def changeset(model, params \\ :{}) do
    model
    |> cast(params, [:title])
    |> cast_assoc(:todo_items)
  end 
end
```

`TodoItem` model:

```
defmodule MyApp.TodoItem do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "todo_items" do
    field :body, :string

    belongs_to :todo_list, MyApp.TodoList

    timestamps
  end

  def changeset(model, params \\ :{}) do
    model
    |> cast(params, [:body])
  end
end
```

Here is the form creation a `TodoList`. To keep things simple let's just add one item for now.

```
<%= form_for @changeset, todo_lists_path(@conn, :create), fn f -> %>    
  <%= text_input f, :title %>  
  <%= inputs_for f, :todo_items, fn i -> %> 
    <%= text_input i, :body %> 
  <% end %>   
  <button name="button" type="submit">Create</button> 
<% end %>
```

This is how `TodoListController` would look like. The `create` method was the trickiest to get right. I had to dig into Ecto Tests to find a way to make this work. [Link](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/6f1971f4120b84e1a441792feb77ba451c4fc783/integration_test/cases/repo.exs#L633)

```
defmodule MyApp.TodoListController do
  use MyApp.Web, :controller

  alias MyApp.TodoList
  alias MyApp.TodoItem

  def new(conn, _params) do
    todo_item = TodoItem.changeset(%TodoItem{})
    changeset = TodoList.changeset(%TodoList{todo_items: [todo_item]})

    render conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset
  end

  def create(conn, %{"todo_list" => todo_list_params}) do
    todo_item_changeset =
      TodoItem.changeset(%TodoItem{}, todo_item["todo_items"]["0"])
    changeset =
      TodoList.changeset(%TodoList{}, %{title: todo_list_params["title"]})
      |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:todo_items, [todo_item_changeset])

    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, company} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "TodoList created!")
        |> redirect(to: page_path(conn, :index))
      {:error, changeset} ->
        conn
        |> render "new.html", changeset: changeset
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Any idea how to add multiple items, dynamically adding / removing them in form?