# How to make forms and transactions play well in phoenix + ecto?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm playing with Phoenix + Ecto and I stumbled upon something that does not feel idiomatic to me.

I have a form that represents an `Invitation`. When creating an Invitation we also need to create a `User` and obviously I want both to happen in a transaction so I keep data consistency. In my form I ask for `name` and `email`.

Since I want the `Invitation` changeset in my view to represent the errors correctly I ended up with this code... but does not look great.

Do you know a better way to do this in Phoenix + Ecto?

```ex
def create(params) do
  Repo.transaction(fn ->
    case Repo.insert(User.email_changeset(%User{}, params)) do
      {:ok, user} ->
        changeset = Invitation.changeset(%Invitation{}, params)
        case Repo.insert(Ecto.Changeset.change(changeset, user_id: user.id)) do
          {:ok, user} ->
            user
          {:error, changeset} ->
            Repo.rollback(changeset)
        end
      {:error, _changeset} ->
        Repo.rollback(%{Ecto.Changeset.add_error(changeset, :email, "Wrong email") | action: :insert})
    end
  end)
end
```

Answer (score 11):

You are looking for the `with` operator. The beauty of this syntax is that if, at any point, you don't get what you're expecting, it stops the chain of commands and fires your `else` block:

```
Repo.transaction(fn ->
  with {:ok, first_object} <- create_some_object,
       {:ok, second_object} <- create_another(first_object.something)  do
       second_object
  else
    {:error, error_key} ->
      Repo.rollback(error_key)
  end
end)
```

if `create_some_object` doesn't return a struct matching {:ok, first_object} then the second_object is never created. Cool, right?

Answer (score 4):

You can try with `Ecto.Multi`.Here's an example:

```
defmodule Service do
  alias Ecto.Multi
  import Ecto

  def insert_changeset(params) do
    Multi.new
    |> Multi.insert(:user, User.email_changeset(%User{}, params))
    |> Multi.insert(:invitation, Invitation.changeset(%Invitation{}, params))
  end
end
```

And your create function:

```
def create(params) do
  Service.insert_changeset(params)
  |> Repo.transaction
end
```

Or you can pattern matching to make your code nicer

```
  def create(params) do
    Repo.transaction(fn ->
      changeset = User.email_changeset(%User{}, params)
      changeset
      |> Repo.insert
      |> invitation_insert(params)
    end)
  end

  defp invitation_insert({:error, changeset}, _params), do: Repo.rollback(changeset)
  defp invitation_insert({:ok, _}, params) do
    Invitation.changeset(%Invitation{}, params)
    |> Repo.insert
    |> do_invitation_insert
  end

  defp do_invitation_insert({:ok, user}), do: user
  defp do_invitation_insert({:error, changeset}), do: Repo.rollback(changeset)
```

Comment: I thought of using a `Multi` but in my case I need to create the `user` first since I need the `user_id` for my Invitation. It looks like `Multi` is for "parallel" operations. The pattern matching version looks much better indeed!

Comment: Would `defp do_invitation_insert({:error, changeset}), do: Repo.rollback(changeset)` also rollback `User`?

Comment: @Omin yes, it is still inside the same transaction

Comment: How do you return errors from Ecto.Multi back to the form, though?