# Phoenix HTML - how to generate nested form

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm coming from PHP Symfony2 framework. Imagine you have models `User` and `Address`

```ruby
schema "users" do
  field :name, :string
  has_many :addresses, App.Address
end
```

```ruby
schema "addresses" do
  field :street, :string
  field :city, :string
  ...
  belongs_to :user, App.User
end
```

I want to create form for `User` with multiple `Address` subforms. I have already read [Working with Ecto associations and embeds](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/08/working-with-ecto-associations-and-embeds/) which describes how to edit and remove items from collections. But there's nothing about adding new ones dynamically, I mean generating a subform for new `Address`. In Symfony there is something called ["prototype"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype), a simple function that generates form for item in collection. It generates inputs with names like `name="addresses[__name__][city]"`. Then I need to replace in JS `__name__` with proper index of item in collection. I didn't find any equivalent of that in Phoenix.

I did an ugly code which works similar to Symfony's way:

```slim
<% {:safe, prototype}
  = form_for App.User.changeset(
      %App.User{addresses: [%App.Address{}]}
    ), "", fn f2 ->
    inputs_for f2, :addresses, fn i2 ->
      render("form_address.html", i: i2)
    end
  end
%>

<div data-prototype="<%= prototype %>">
  <%= inputs_for f, :addresses, fn i -> %>
    <%= render "form_address.html", i: i %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<button type="button">
  Add address
</button>
```

When I click *Add address* JS replaces `[0]` and `_0_` in attributes of inputs (for example `name="addresses[0][city]"`) with proper indexes and adds new item in collection. It works, but is there any right way of doing this?

Comment: I think this other question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32054561/how-to-handle-associations-and-nested-forms-in-phoenix-framework

Comment: @neydroid in answer to that question was association 1-1, with hardcoded in controller one `Engine` to a one `Car`, so Phoenix was able to generate nicely this one subform. I need to dynamically add a new subform via JavaScript to  association 1-many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my own form library for Phoenix - [Formex](https://github.com/jakub-zawislak/formex). It supports [nested forms](https://hexdocs.pm/formex/Formex.Type.html#module-nested-forms) and [collections of forms](https://hexdocs.pm/formex/Formex.Type.html#module-collections-of-forms), i.e. `one_to_one` and `one_to_many` relations.

Comment: it works fine with liveview?